# Project Euler #246: Tangents to an ellipse Angle between Tangents

Tags: python-3.x, math, geometry, angle, ellipse

I used shift of origin and tried to solve [problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler246/problem)

[My Similar question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68858346/angle-between-tangents-to-ellipse-from-external-points-with-slopes-of-tangents)

and now that ellipse after shift of origin has equation `(x/a)^2+(y/b)^2=1`
so after **condition of tangency to ellipse** `(am)^2+b^2=c^2` where `c = y0-mx0` solved for `m` where `D = (x0, y0)` is variable point in only **+quadrant as ellipse is symmetrical about axes number of lattice points for which the angle between tangents is greater than given angle will be multiplied by 2 if point D is on either axes else with 4**

But now I'm unable to find the expected angle **α**  which to this contrast program may result in **(180-α)** or **(90-α)** or whatever but is not giving **α always**

[image]

**Input**

```
64817 64819 11420
3
30 1
```

**Output**

```
1.5 1.118033988749895      #values of a, b of ellipse
88.09084756700362          #Given angle
0 2 84.26082952273322      # x, y, and angle
0 3 56.63298703076825
0 4 42.667925494108374
0 5 34.21605113129826
0 6 28.552637360182302
1 1 132.1304147613666
1 2 105.37675990405205
1 3 126.93618989341962
1 4 138.99680040248643
1 5 146.68139315999935
1 6 151.98229919837212
2 0 99.59406822686043
2 1 70.40251628700852
2 2 123.92838964927597      #In figure it is 56.0716 while it's supplementary angle
2 3 135.0795775738836
2 4 143.16521634758482
2 5 149.05461064130475
2 6 153.44570404972666
3 0 133.43253655778977
3 1 45.1685179704227
3 2 138.68062832170193
3 3 143.5441803020086
3 4 148.1966760890815
3 5 152.19282398152126
3 6 155.49812437089727
4 0 146.4426902380793
4 1 33.150772763942314
4 2 148.18918752912822
4 3 150.3525987174534
4 4 152.8971875924072
4 5 155.43753093848753
4 6 157.77424382459193
5 0 153.61567025059207
5 1 26.21616761276448
5 2 154.36403775389698
5 3 155.4135197186744
5 4 156.82314264518547
5 5 158.40584822123196
5 6 160.005114518988
6 0 158.21321070173815
6 1 21.70150969841879
6 2 158.59334015511746
6 3 159.1528282819498
6 4 159.9664352057684
6 5 160.96054819665326
6 6 162.04466838669927
```

**Code**

```
from math import atan
from math import acos
from math import degrees
from math import atan2
from math import sqrt
from operator import gt
from operator import abs
class P_test():
    def __init__(self,x,y,a,b):
        self.x, self.y, self.a, self.b = x, y, a, b
    
    def Region(self):                # Tests if point(x,y) is out of region of ellipse
        if (self.x/self.a)**2 + (self.y/self.b)**2 >1:
            return 1
    
    def T_angle(self):              # Returns angle between tangents but not expected None
        x, y = self.x, self.y
        A, B , C = self.a**2-self.x**2, 2*self.x*self.y, self.b**2-self.y**2
        D = sqrt(B**2-4*A*C)
        m1, m2 = (-B+D)/(2*A), (-B-D)/(2*A)
        alpha1 = degrees(acos(1/(sqrt(1+m1**2))))        
        alpha2 = degrees(acos(1/(sqrt(1+m2**2))))
        if x*y: return 180-degrees(abs(atan2(y,y/m1)-atan2(y,y/m2)))
        return 180-abs(alpha2)-abs(alpha1)
    
class Datasource():
    def __init__(self, cordinate, radius, pq):
        self.xy, self.r, self.pq = cordinate, radius, pq
    
    def a_b_of_ellipse(self):
        x1, x2, y, r = self.xy[0], self.xy[1], self.xy[2], self.r
        H, K = x1 + (x2-x1)/2, y
        mx, my = x1-H, y-K
        gx, gy = x2-H, y-K
        ae = (mx-gx)/2
        a =gx + (r-(x2-x1))/2
        b = sqrt(a**2-ae**2)
        return a, b
    
    def G_angle(self):
        return degrees(atan(self.pq[0]/self.pq[1]))
    
    
    
xy_cord = list(map(int, input().split()))
radius = int(input())
pq = list(map(int, input().split()))
r1 = Datasource(xy_cord, radius, pq)
aa, bb, G = r1.a_b_of_ellipse()[0], r1.a_b_of_ellipse()[1], r1.G_angle()
print(aa, bb); print(G)
for x in range(0,7):
    for y in range(0,7):
        r2 = P_test(x,y,aa,bb)
        if r2.Region():
            print(x,y,r2.T_angle())
```

**How can I find Only Alpha Angle**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But you can calculate tangent points, so no need in using slopes - just get alpha from triangle TP1-D-TP2

Comment: You need such points D, but for every D you can calculate two points where lines from D tangent the ellipse. For now you calculate tnagent slopes, but you can caclulate points thmeselves and use them to get proper solution without doubts.

Answer (score 0):

```
from math import atan, acos, degrees, atan2, sqrt
from operator import gt, abs
class P_test():
    def __init__(self, x, y, a,b):
        self.x, self.y, self.a, self.b = x, y, a, b
    
    def Region(self):
        if self.x**2/self.a**2 + self.y**2/self.b**2 >1:
            return 1
        
    def Slope(self):
        x, y = self.x, self.y
        A, B, C = self.a**2-self.x**2, 2*self.x*self.y, self.b**2-self.y**2
        D = sqrt(B**2-4*A*C)
        m1, m2 = (-B+D)/(2*A), (-B-D)/(2*A)
        return m1, m2
        
class Datasource():
    def __init__(self, cordinate, radius, pq):
        self.xy, self.r, self.pq = cordinate, radius, pq

    def a_b_of_ellipse(self):
        x1, x2, y, r = self.xy[0], self.xy[1], self.xy[2], self.r
        H, K = x1+(x2-x1)/2, y
        mx, my = x1-H, K
        gx, gy = x2-H, y-K
        ae = (mx-gx)/2
        a = gx + (r-(x2-x1))/2
        b = sqrt(a**2-ae**2)
        return a, b

    def G_angle(self):
        return degrees(atan(self.pq[0]/self.pq[1]))
    
    
def Touchpoint(x,y,m1,m2,a,b):
    c1,c2 = y-m1*x, y-m2*x
    return -a**2*m1/c1, b**2/c1, -a**2*m2/c2, b**2/c2

xy_cord = list(map(int, input().split()))
radius = int(input())
pq = list(map(int, input().split()))
r1 = Datasource(xy_cord, radius, pq)
aa, bb, G = r1.a_b_of_ellipse()[0], r1.a_b_of_ellipse()[1], r1.G_angle()
#print(aa,bb)
#print(G)
count = 0
for x in range(0, 100000):
    for y in range(0, 100000):
        r2 = P_test(x,y,aa,bb)
        if r2.Region():
            slope1, slope2 = r2.Slope()[0], r2.Slope()[1]
            #if r2.T_angle()>=G:
            Z = Touchpoint(x,y,slope1,slope2, aa, bb)
            px1,py1,px2,py2 = Z[0], Z[1], Z[2], Z[3]
            M = [degrees(atan2((y-py1),(x-px1))), degrees(atan2((y-py2),(x-px2)))]
            if abs(M[1]-M[0])>=G:
            #    print(x,y, abs(M[1]-M[0]))
                if x*y==0:
                    count += 2
                else:
                    count +=4
            else: break
print(count)
```